# Docker Compose run a command

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I would like to run a command with docker compose, it is not working, the container starts and disappear without any errors

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "8888:80"
    volumes:
        - ./dir:/dir
    command: bash -c "chown -R www-data:www-data /dir"
    links:
        - php
```

I think that the command is being executed but the container stops then, should I add something else ?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do and recommend is to use commands only inside Dockerfile (`RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /dir`). If you need to run anything at "boot time" (for example keep container running), you can do this at your docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
    - "8888:80"
volumes:
    - ./dir:/dir
entrypoint: /root/start_services.sh
links:
    - php
```

and inside start_services.sh, you need to run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to keep the container runnning.

start_services.sh file is copyied into /root dir inside container.

Comment: Same thing the container works fine but disappear.. even with a infinite while loop